# Animals popping up randomly

Tags: chromium, extension

There are pictures of animals that are popping up randomly on my computer.  When I move the mouse over the animal it turns into a a sword icon, and when I click it, the animal disappears but after a few minutes another animal comes up.  I think it may be related to Chromium but I'm not sure.

What is this and how can I get rid of it?

[image: strange animal]

Comment: Give it to me, I take it!

Comment: Really, Really weird.... We will try our "beast" to hlep you :P

Comment: Please list the extensions you have installed. You can find this out by entering chrome://extensions/ in the url bar. Also, post the output of `ps ax`.

Comment: I was not able to stop my laughter at this question :D

Comment: I found it... it was a Chrome extension (I think called "MMO")... I uninstalled it and the animals went back to their holes :)

Comment: @oriole - well done - please post that as an answer which you can accept (probably in a few hours time if you cant immediately after posting).  Many thanks.

Comment: How did you take the image inside your brain?

Comment: This is the BEST QUESTION in askubuntu ever. It made me laugh so hard IRL! :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it... it was a Chrome extension (I think called "MMO")... I uninstalled it and the animals went back to their holes :)

Comment: That's animal cruelty if you ask me. I'm calling the AUPCA.

Answer (score 17):

If you are not joking then this can be a mistake. May be there is some web script or a background process running.

So what you can do is:

1. Close browser and see if animal appears again.
2. If appears again then type `ps -A` in terminal and watch for any suspicious process and terminate it as soon as you see it.
3. If you can not see any suspicious process, restart your computer.
4. If nothing works feed it what it wants and pray to God that it runs away without harming you.
   :D

Comment: Very funny :-) ...+1 vote

Comment: Best question ever, and best answer, specially #4 xD